# NTFS-3g HDD 0770 and 0777 permissions Owncloud

Tags: linux

I want to install owncloud on my Raspberry-pi (Model B), I've got it running but only on my SD-card. Now i want to set the data on my External HDD.

I've added the follow line in /etc/fstab, so the HDD will be mounted on boot.

> /dev/sda1       /media/New/     ntfs-3g rw,gid=500,umask=0007,defauts 0 0

Umask is setting the permission to 0770, this is necessary by owncloud. But the data directory (in my case /media/New/Cl/data) must be 0777. Is there a way to set the permissions of every folder to 0770 except the data directory? (0777)

I'm using my hard disk for other data to, so formatting the disk to an other format isn't really possible.

I'm new to Linux, so any help is welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this question is hard to answer, so I've bought a USB flash drive for testing. It worked immediately after formatting to ext4.

Answer (score 1):

I attempted to setup an owncloud as well with my Raspberry Pi 2.

On the first time many errors occurred, although I managed to get the owncloud running on an external 500GB NTFS drive (it also worked well on my Fat32 partition).

Sometimes there was an error with the permissions on the external drive which needed `chmod` and `chown` to fix. For example: if I didn't set the ownership properly with:

```
sudo chown -R username:groupname /mnt/usbstorage/owncloud`
```

*[Editor note: putting in the right things for `username:groupname`, it wasn't specified pre-edit, possibly `pi:users`]*
it didn't work at all...

Just in case you are still willing to try this again or for future reference.

Try to add this information to your `etc/fstab` with say `sudo nano /etc/fstab`:

```
UUID=4234A32424A234EE /mnt/usbstorage ntfs  defaults,nls=utf8,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=007,windows_names 0 0
```

You may need `nfts-3g` instead of `ntfs`.

Then afterwards reboot with `sudo reboot`. Tada! The error 0770 should be gone. Hope it helps!

Comment: You will need to have the correct UUID for the drive/filesystem you wish to mount - you can usually get this from the output of the `blkid` utility (run as root or with `sudo`).  The mount point should already exist (as an, ideally empty, directory), which in this case is `/mnt/usbstorage`.

Comment: Thanks for edit and clarity @SlySven . I'm quite new here so still a lot to learn :)